# Are there general way to construct Green's function of a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I want to know if there are general way to construct Green's function. I understand the Green's may not have explicit formula for a PDE consider in general. But what I want to know is as follow:

Suppose I have an operator $Lv=0$ on a Domain. If based on $L$, the backward Kolmogorov equation and forward Kolmogorov equation, denoted by $L\phi=0$ and $L^{*}\psi=0$ are solvable and have explicit formula, can I construct Green's function based on $\phi$ and $\psi$ for $L$ on the given Domain. For example, if $L=\partial_{t}+\partial_{xx}$ and $L^{*}=\partial_{t}+\partial_{xx}$ and $L\phi=0$ and $L^{*}\psi=0$ are solvable, can I recover the Green function from the knowledge of $\phi$ and $\psi$?

Comment: In the ODE case yes, because the Green's function is basically just a parameterized family of particular solutions of the homogeneous equation (or a pair of them joined by an intermediate boundary condition, depending on what exactly you mean by Green's function). In the PDE case I think the answer is generally no.

Comment: Any examples showing this?